# Should I use the CreditCardAttribute to validate credit card numbers?

Tags: c#, validation, payment-gateway, credit-card

Should I use Microsoft's [CreditCardAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.creditcardattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to validate credit card numbers like so?

```
[Required, CreditCard]
public string CreditCardNumber { get; set; }
```

Or should I let the payment gateway handle it, or do something else? I ask this after discovering some customers have been unable to submit payment with their credit card information. Fortunately, I was able to work with one of these customers, and found that their Visa card was processed without a problem after removing the `CreditCardAttribute`.

In part, this question is rhetorical, but I would like to benefit from other developer's thoughts and experiences, and make other developers aware of the risks of using the `CreditCardAttribute` by asking the question.

Comment: A link to the documentation of the attribute in question would be very helpful.

Comment: @OndrejTucny [Here you go](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.creditcardattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Quick google search goes a long way.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12580450/3199927) provides some insight into how the `CreditCardAttribute` validates input.

Comment: It would be interesting to hear what was different about that particular customer's card number...

Comment: @Tom and thanks for the link to more info. What I believe I have discovered is that even if the algorithm is 100% correct some credit cards simply don't pass validation because they were not designed to conform to the pattern Luhn is validating, and that is very bad when it means lost revenue.

Comment: @buffjape to my surprise the customer that I worked with had a Visa credit card. I was half expecting a less typical credit card, maybe American Express or Discover. Unfortunately I don't know much beyond that, perhaps their card was a business card, and for some reason business Visa cards don't conform to Luhn. I'm hopefully someone who knows more about credit card validation in general will be able to weigh in.

Comment: @JoshL. It's not about the *speed* of googling, but about the *completeness* of the question.

Comment: BTW I did add a link to the question. Thank you Ondrej for asking and Josh for providing the link.

Comment: @OndrejTucny You're right, didn't mean to sound snarky.

Comment: If you are using to validate, I would recommend relying on the gateway/platform you have integrated to for card validation. They typically have a direct integration to the Processors which pass down a BIN range file on a regular basis to allow for a more accurate check.

Comment: @IanLink that's what I've decided to do for now because it seems more reliable, but PaulG is contending in his answer that the algorithm should work on pretty much every credit card. So I'm still wondering what went wrong. Perhaps I made some mistake. I see you've been in payment processing for 5 years. Have you ran into issues with credit card sanity check not passing?

Comment: Honestly, I have always relied on my Gateway team to pull down the BIN files and do the validation for specific transactions (FSA/IIAS), otherwise we only do a simple count of the digits and let the Processor do the hard work. I don't trust a 3rd party (MS in this case) to have a reliable check since it can change quickly and often at times. I have seen a few times where a card brand is incorrectly deduced or not at all when the BIN file was old or corrupt. Case in point, recently PayPal purchased a BIN range from Discover and will eventually be theirs and no longer be a Disc brand.

Comment: @IanLink. You've misunderstood. This is **not** a BIN range check, just a **luhn digit** check. (For the record I agree that BIN range checking is pointless unless you have access to the latest IIN database from the ABA. Once the luhn digit is validated it is best to send it to the processor, as I said in my answer below)

Comment: @PaulG, I absolutely agree with you, I was just saying that I have not relied on luhn checks unless absolutely necessary because of false positives, and instead allowed the transaction to fail or (for sake of cost) tokenize the card and use the gateway's check on the card. I know that my gateway team has developed a very comprehensive card validation check (luhn, bin range, etc) and I do not wish to duplicate the code. Nearly all credit cards would pass the luhn but I was saying some non card numbers would too.

Comment: @IanLink. You said 'Nearly all credit cards would pass the luhn'. Just to be black and white about this... do you know any credit cards that **fail a luhn check, but are otherwise valid**? In my 10+ years experience, countless millions of transactions, I have never seen that. And *that* is what Jeremy is claiming to see here.

Comment: @PaulG, only a Diners Club card range and a small brand in China that was bought by UnionPay (I forget the name). The number of cards which would not pass is so small, I would agree to say it is a valid check. I'm only bringing up the possible issue of false positives.

Comment: @IanLink and PaulG it is sounding like there is consensus that a luhn check failure, such as what I think I experienced, is extremely unlikely. I really appreciate all the input from people who have been doing this for a while! It's unfortunately a bit of a ghost chase since retaining credit card numbers is a big no-no, but you've inspired me to take a closer look at how I'm using the CreditCardAttribute and the JavaScript it emits. Perhaps I'm using it in an unexpected way.

Comment: Well @PaulG and Ian, I looked into JavaScript validation being the issue but the CreditCardAttribute does not emit any. So that's out of the question. I also looked at the transactions in PayPal's portal and verified that the customer did use a Visa card, and used it many times before the CreditCardAttribute was in place and after I removed it.

Answer (score 6):

In the [code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/CreditCardAttribute.cs,15) behind the credit card [attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.creditcardattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), it is simply performing a [Luhn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) check.

All payment cards(*) currently follow [ISO/IEC/7812](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_7812) standard, which has a luhn check digit as the final digit.

This luhn check is simply used to prevent transpositional errors though. It is useful as a sanity check prior to submitting card numbers to a payment gateway, but not suitable to absolutely validate whether a number is a valid card number.

Valid card number ranges change monthly, and the only way to absolutely verify a number is to validate it via a payment gateway. If only attempting to validate a card (rather than charge it) this should be done with a zero value 'authorisation only' style check.

(*) *The only exception to this is a card type in China known as China UnionPay

 (Historically there was also a Diners Club 'enRoute' brand which was withdrawn in 1992)*

Comment: Would you provide some evidence that supports your assertion that "all payment cards currently follow the Luhn algorithm"? It would seem either Microsoft has incorrectly implemented a simple and well known algorithm, or your assertion is wrong.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with Microsoft's implementation. It's a valid luhn check algorithm. If however you feed it invalid test data, you'll get a invalid test result.. as expected :)  The last remaining test you have that doesn't pass is an 11 digit number. This is way to short for a valid card number which are *usually* 16 digits minimum. (Format is usually a 6 digit IIN, last digit as a check digit, remainder as unique account number). This would mean that Dankort card only has 10,000 valid account numbers? Seems unlikely :)

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding you but it seems that you believe the problem I've encountered doesn't exist. I was lucky enough to catch this problem early :) Of about 20 customers who got to the payment page, at least one of them, with a 16 digit Visa card number, got stuck at the CreditCardAttribute validation. Once I removed that attribute the customer was able to submit their payment without issue. I understand that Luhn is a standard and also believe that MS's implementation is fine, but finding that one of the first 20 customers had a "non-standard" credit card number is surprising.

Comment: I'd also find it very surprising. You have to imagine (ballparking here) 80% of online merchants perform a luhn check validation prior to authorization. So this one 'valid' card would have been invalid at 80% of stores? Is that likely, or is it more likely that someone made a typo in the card number? :)  I also imagine that when you did remove the luhn check and sent it for auth, it was probably declined by the payment service provider? Would be **hugely** surprised to find a number with invalid luhn that also authorizes.

Comment: I could be wrong but I'm almost completely certain there was no typo. I worked with the customer, and when the CreditCardAttribute was in use we couldn't finish submitting the form due to validation. Once it was removed the payment was authorized, then captured, completing the process. It does sound crazy and I'm also surprised. I'm starting to wonder if maybe the CreditCardAttribute's JavaScript validation might be the culprit. I haven't seen anyone comment on its validity, and can't say whether it was the client side or server side credit card validation that failed.

Answer (score 5):

I think the best way to find this out is to simply test it:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace SO
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] cards = new string[] {
                //http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm
                "378282246310005",  // American Express
                "4012888888881881", // Visa
                "6011111111111117", // Discover
                "4222222222222", // Visa
                "76009244561", // Dankort (PBS)
                "5019717010103742", // Dakort (PBS) 
                "6331101999990016", // Switch/Solo (Paymentech)
                "30569309025904", // Diners Club 
                //http://www.getcreditcardnumbers.com/
                "5147004213414803", // Mastercard
                "6011491706918120", // Discover
                "379616680189541", // American Express
                "4916111026621797", // Visa
            };

            foreach (string card in cards)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(IsValid(card));
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                return true;
            }

            string ccValue = value as string;
            if (ccValue == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            ccValue = ccValue.Replace("-", "");
            ccValue = ccValue.Replace(" ", "");

            int checksum = 0;
            bool evenDigit = false;

            // http://www.beachnet.com/~hstiles/cardtype.html
            foreach (char digit in ccValue.Reverse())
            {
                if (digit < '0' || digit > '9')
                {
                    return false;
                }

                int digitValue = (digit - '0') * (evenDigit ? 2 : 1);
                evenDigit = !evenDigit;

                while (digitValue > 0)
                {
                    checksum += digitValue % 10;
                    digitValue /= 10;
                }
            }

            return (checksum % 10) == 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The IsValid method is from the original C# [CreditCardAttribute](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/CreditCardAttribute.cs,15) class.
1 out of the 12 numbers failed:

```
        True
        True
        True
        True
        False //"76009244561", // Dankort (PBS)
        True
        True
        True
        True
        True
        True
        True
```

So, should you use it? No, obviously it doesn't detect all numbers. Although you can take their code and improve it!

Comment: Very nice take on the problem! I wish it gave me the confidence to use "improved" validation. Unfortunately it seems to demonstrate exactly what I fear. The list of credit card numbers seems incomplete because I was told it was a Visa card. I expected one of the fails to be Visa. The customer may have been wrong, but I'm doubtful of that. It still seems to me that using credit card validation in this way is risky, even if you have a lot of fake credit card numbers to test with. After all, Visa could put out new numbers tomorrow that my custom, totally up-to-date, validation may fail.

Comment: Indeed, this has been discussed numerous times on the web now, the usage of the Luhn algorithm isn't covering all of the existing credit cards. I guess the only way to be 100% certain is to validate it by actually executing the transaction.

Comment: Having said that, if I were forced to validate in my code for some reason, having a unit test like this is definitely the way to go. In addition to that I would want logging (not of the credit card numbers used!) but number of validation fails so that I might be able to consider if my validator is producing false negatives.

Comment: I wish I had thought to look for those credit card validation discussions before releasing my app. I never expected the validator to be too restrictive. I'm afraid I assumed Microsoft's validator could be trusted completely and that at worse it would be not restrictive enough. My mistake for not testing. Thanks for demonstrating how well it does and does not work with  code!

Comment: Not sure where you got the card numbers from, but my AMEX 'EBG' documentation states that Amex card numbers are always 15 digits long, starting with 34 or 37. It gives an example of '3742 5103 2182 013'.

Comment: The links are in the comments above the items in the array. Just noted that the Microsoft article is dated at '04, thus I've removed it from the code/results as the card numbers they provide aren't functional anymore.